# Wheatstone bridge calculation

Tags: arduino, thermistor, wheatstone-bridge

`R4` is [thermistor](http://dscelec.co.kr/board/main.cgi/5D20.pdf?down_num=1151457156&board=data&command=down_load&d=&filename=5D20.pdf) with `R25` value of `5 Ohm`, `Beta is 3150`. `V` should be at most `1V` because I want to use internal `1V1` reference voltage. `V` supply is 5V. I don't really want to use OpAmp to keep it simple. The problem is also to draw as less current from power supply as possible. Accuracy can be 2-3C, range is 20-80C.

I tried to use some Wheatstone bridge calculators, but I don't get the bridge balanced and to draw acceptable current.

[image]

Comment: Which resistor are you varying to  balance the bridge?

Comment: I've tried to vary `R3`.

Comment: Thermistor range looks like 0.8 to 6 ohms. Doing this with low current and no amplifier looks like a difficult problem. Did you actually have a question?

Comment: @BrianDrummond: the question was `R1-R3` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
This should get you close.  By my calcs, in your range the thermistor will be going from about 1 ohm to about 6 ohms.  With a 1K resistor to hold currents down to milliamps, you need a gain of about 35 to keep your max voltage at 1V.  This circuit has a gain of 34 using standard 5% resistor values.  You might need to change to a rail-to-rail op amp if you're going to power it with a one-sided supply.

Comment: Could you plz give me one rail-to-rail amp example which I can use here?

Comment: http://aldinc.com/pdf/ALD2702.pdf, assuming you need a DIP package, which limits your options.  Alternatively, you can just use the tl081 with two power supplies, plus and minus Vcc

Answer (score 0):

The resistance change of thermistors is generally big enough that you don't need a Wheatstone bridge.  Just put the thermistor in an op-amp circuit.  If you need to linearize the thermistor, that's done with an appropriately chosen series or parallel resistor -- http://www.ecircuitcenter.com/Circuits/therm_ckt1/therm_ckt1.htm

Comment: So there is no way to avoid OpAmp? Would it introduce additional non-linearity to thermistor? Would it introduce distortion due to noises? I have TL081. If so then please correct your answer to state that Wheatstone bridge will not do the job and I will open new question with OpAmp.

Comment: Do you have a part number for the thermistor??  5 ohms seems like a low resistance for a thermistor.  No need to open a new question.  See http://www.barrgroup.com/images/glossary/T_ThermistorCircuit.gif on http://www.barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/Glossary-T for a real simple thermistor circuit.  A  Wheatstone bridge will certainly do the job, but they're also generally used with a differential amp, any you'll have a tradeoff between proper bridge balance and how much current you draw.  In the circuit above, there is a tradeoff between sensitivity and current, but gain can added if needed.

Comment: NTC 5D-20. Did you check datasheet in my original post?

Comment: But how can I control this simple circuit to give me max 1V output? Also I'm sure this circuit is not accustomed for 5 Ohm thermistor.

Comment: Now I'm confused... should I used only Wheatstone bridge or with OpAmp combination?

Comment: This thermistor has low resistance to keep power lower for large currents.  It's a large current thermistor. Proper bridge R values will be in the ohms range.  If you want a low current application, your sensitivity will be low, and you will need a gain stage whether or not you're using a Wheatstone bridge

Comment: I need low current application and mentally ready to gain it with TL081. Could you tell me what value of bias resistor should be? Also the same question - would TL081 introduce additional non-linearity?

Comment: Compared to a typical NTC, TL081 has no nonlinearity at all.